# Logic behind selecting number of peers for an organization in hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hi I am looking to find what is the logic behind selecting number of peers in Hyperledger fabric for an organization

Answer (score 3):

The more peers you have, the more transaction simulations you can do per second.

Since in fabric not all peers run the smart contracts but only the minimum number needed to satisfy the endorsement policy, if you have i.e 10 peers but you only need 1 of them to sign an endorsement, that means you can endorse 10 transactions "in the same time" as 1 transaction and this would increase the throughput of the system, provided that the validation and commit can withhold such a rate of transactions.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK:
1 peer = 1 Org = 1 Peer admin

If you set up a company network, where every department needs an individual peer admin. You would use multiple Orgs within this company.

Each client gets access through its department-peer.

Please correct me if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: This can be arbitrary and there is no such a relation. A peer admin is a "local" setting of the peer.